# Changing the Reference value of a Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, alter

I have created a table 'company' having the column actor_id referencing the primary key (id) of the table 'actor'. Now I want to change the column actor_id to reference the primary key (id) of the table director. After trying to drop the foreign key, and creating a new one referencing the new table, it did not work as desired, it stayed the same - referencing the previous (actor) table. What changes should I make?

```
CREATE TABLE company(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
actor_id INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT aID FOREIGN KEY (actor_id) REFERENCES actor(id),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

```
 ALTER TABLE company
 DROP FOREIGN KEY aID,
 ADD CONSTRAINT actID FOREIGN KEY (actor_id) REFERENCES director(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any apparent issues in the code above. I tried same in SQL Fiddle which works. You can check the link.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82e334c/2/0